# How to make tkinter whiteboard transparent?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I made a whiteboard where I can draw lines on it.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkbootstrap import Style

class Whiteboard:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Whiteboard')
        self.master.resizable(True,True)
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        
        #set ttkbootstrap style
        self.style = Style(theme = 'pulse')
        self.master.configure(bg='white')


        #create canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master,width=1200,height=600)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        #create buttons
        self.button_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.button_frame.pack(side='top',pady=10)

        #button configuration
        button_config = {
            'black':('dark.TButton',lambda:self.change_color('black')),
            'red':('danger.TButton',lambda:self.change_color('red')),
            'blue':('info.TButton',lambda:self.change_color('blue')),
            'green':('success.TButton',lambda:self.change_color('green')),
            'yellow':('warning.TButton',lambda:self.change_color('yellow')),
            'clear':('light.TButton',self.clear_canvas),
        }

        #add buttons to the button frame
        for color,(style_name,command) in button_config.items():
            ttk.Button(self.button_frame,text=color.capitalize(),
                       command=command,style=style_name).pack(side='left',anchor='s', fill='y',padx=3,pady=3)
     
        #initialize drawing variables
        self.draw_color = 'black'
        self.line_width = 5
        self.old_x,self.old_y = None, None

        #all event listeners
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>',self.start_line)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>',self.draw_line)

    #save starting point of line
    def start_line(self,event):
        self.old_x,self.old_y = event.x, event.y
    
    #draw line from starting point to current point and then update starting point
    def draw_line(self,event):
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            self.canvas.create_line(self.old_x,self.old_y, event.x, event.y, 
                                    width=self.line_width,fill= self.draw_color,
                                    capstyle=tk.ROUND,smooth=tk.TRUE)
            self.old_x,self.old_y = event.x,event.y

    #update current drawing color 
    def change_color(self,new_color):
        self.draw_color = new_color
    
    #delete all objects on canvas
    def clear_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.delete('all')

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    whiteboard = Whiteboard(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

However, I want to make the white part transparent.

I tried:

```
self.master.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor',self.master['bg'])
```

It does make it transparent but I can no more draw on it. I will select the program behind it if I click on it.

[image]

I also tried this below but It seems it doesn't work on Tk().Canvas().

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
```

What can I do to make a transparent paint board?

Comment: you may have to use different framework - ie. `PyQt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can suggest is a kind of trick.
First, install the necessary libraries.
`pip install pywin32`, `pip install pillow`

And load the library.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkbootstrap import Style
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
```

And prepare a full-screen screenshot before the window is created.

```
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(78)
        self.screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(79)
        self.full_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, self.screen_width, self.screen_height), all_screens=True)
```

Create an empty image object on the canvas.

```
        # create canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.image_obj = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=None)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
```

Now let's add an event.

```
        # all event listeners
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.start_line)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_line)
        self.master.bind('<Configure>', self.screen_update)
```

And add a function.

```
    def screen_update(self, event):
        self.img = self.full_image.crop((self.canvas.winfo_rootx(),
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rooty(),
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rootx() + 800, # your master geometry x
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rooty() + 600)) # your master geometry y
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img, master=self.master)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_obj, image=self.imgtk)
```

So the full code is

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkbootstrap import Style
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

class Whiteboard:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(78)
        self.screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(79)
        self.full_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, self.screen_width, self.screen_height), all_screens=True)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Whiteboard')
        self.master.resizable(True, True)
        self.master.geometry("800x600")

        # set ttkbootstrap style
        self.style = Style(theme='pulse')
        self.master.configure(bg='white')

        # create canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.image_obj = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=None)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        # create buttons
        self.button_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.button_frame.pack(side='top', pady=10)

        # button configuration
        button_config = {
            'black': ('dark.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('black')),
            'red': ('danger.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('red')),
            'blue': ('info.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('blue')),
            'green': ('success.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('green')),
            'yellow': ('warning.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('yellow')),
            'clear': ('light.TButton', self.clear_canvas),
        }

        # add buttons to the button frame
        for color, (style_name, command) in button_config.items():
            ttk.Button(self.button_frame, text=color.capitalize(),
                       command=command, style=style_name).pack(side='left', anchor='s', fill='y', padx=3, pady=3)

        # initialize drawing variables
        self.draw_color = 'black'
        self.line_width = 5
        self.old_x, self.old_y = None, None

        # all event listeners
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.start_line)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_line)
        self.master.bind('<Configure>', self.screen_update)


    def screen_update(self, event):
        self.img = self.full_image.crop((self.canvas.winfo_rootx(),
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rooty(),
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rootx() + 800, # your master geometry x
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rooty() + 600)) # your master geometry y
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img, master=self.master)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_obj, image=self.imgtk)

    # save starting point of line
    def start_line(self, event):
        self.old_x, self.old_y = event.x, event.y

    # draw line from starting point to current point and then update starting point
    def draw_line(self, event):
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            self.canvas.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                                    width=self.line_width, fill=self.draw_color,
                                    capstyle=tk.ROUND, smooth=tk.TRUE)
            self.old_x, self.old_y = event.x, event.y

    # update current drawing color
    def change_color(self, new_color):
        self.draw_color = new_color

    # delete all objects on canvas
    def clear_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.delete('all')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    whiteboard = Whiteboard(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I hope it will be of help.

Comment: That is such a genius way of solution! It perfectly fulfills my need! I also adjusted the code, making the screenshot size change with the window size change, and also changed the clear function so that the screenshot won't be deleted, the code is below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by kimhyunju. I adjusted the code a little,and it works perfectly now. I also added refresh screen in the ‘clear’ button。

```
import tkinter as tk
from ttkbootstrap import Style
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk
# from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from screeninfo import get_monitors

class Whiteboard:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # self.screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(78)
        # self.screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(79)
        self.primary_monitor = get_monitors()[0]
        self.full_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, self.primary_monitor.width, self.primary_monitor.height), all_screens=True)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Whiteboard')
        self.master.resizable(True, True)
        self.master.geometry("800x600")

        # set ttkbootstrap style
        self.style = Style(theme='pulse')
        self.master.configure(bg='white')

        # create canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.image_obj = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=None)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        # create buttons
        self.button_frame = tk.ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.button_frame.pack(side='top', pady=10)

        # button configuration
        button_config = {
            'black': ('dark.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('black')),
            'red': ('danger.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('red')),
            'blue': ('info.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('blue')),
            'green': ('success.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('green')),
            'yellow': ('warning.TButton', lambda: self.change_color('yellow')),
            'clear': ('light.TButton', self.clear_canvas),
        }

        # add buttons to the button frame
        for color, (style_name, command) in button_config.items():
            tk.ttk.Button(self.button_frame, text=color.capitalize(),
                       command=command, style=style_name).pack(side='left', anchor='s', fill='y', padx=3, pady=3)

        # initialize drawing variables
        self.draw_color = 'black'
        self.line_width = 5
        self.old_x, self.old_y = None, None

        # all event listeners
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.start_line)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_line)
        self.master.bind('<Configure>', self.screen_update)


    def screen_update(self, event):
        # self.full_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, self.primary_monitor.width, self.primary_monitor.height), all_screens=True)
        self.img = self.full_image.crop((self.canvas.winfo_rootx(),
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rooty(),
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rootx() + self.master.winfo_width(), # your master geometry x
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rooty() + self.master.winfo_height())) # your master geometry y
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img, master=self.master)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_obj, image=self.imgtk)

    # save starting point of line
    def start_line(self, event):
        self.old_x, self.old_y = event.x, event.y

    # draw line from starting point to current point and then update starting point
    def draw_line(self, event):
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            self.canvas.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                                    width=self.line_width, fill=self.draw_color,
                                    capstyle=tk.ROUND, smooth=tk.TRUE,tags='line')
            self.old_x, self.old_y = event.x, event.y

    # update current drawing color
    def change_color(self, new_color):
        self.draw_color = new_color

    # delete all objects on canvas
    # def clear_canvas(self):
    #     self.canvas.delete('all')
    
    def clear_canvas(self):
        # Get all items on the canvas
        all_items = self.canvas.find_withtag('line')
        # Iterate through all items and delete lines
        for item_id in all_items:
            self.canvas.delete(item_id)
        self.master.attributes('-alpha',0)  # Minimize the window
        self.full_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, self.primary_monitor.width, self.primary_monitor.height), all_screens=True)
        self.master.attributes('-alpha',1) # Restore the window to its normal state

        self.img = self.full_image.crop((self.canvas.winfo_rootx(),
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rooty(),
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rootx() + self.master.winfo_width(), # your master geometry x
                                        self.canvas.winfo_rooty() + self.master.winfo_height())) # your master geometry y
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img, master=self.master)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_obj, image=self.imgtk)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    whiteboard = Whiteboard(root)
    root.mainloop()
```